# How do I Decompile .Pyd file made with python, cython and pyinstaller 3.6

Tags: ida, disassembly, decompilation, c, python

I created an [app](https://github.com/oddsmatcheraustralia/OMAFREE) in 2018 with python and then used Cython and pyinstaller v 3.6.

I am wondering how to decompile it.   I have tried **uncompyle6** + **pyinstxtractor** however this only works for python files, not cython. There is also no known cython decompiler.  I have had a try with **Ghidra** and IDA but no luck although I am new to it.

Answer (score 0):

The `.pyx` file is not embedded in the `.dll`, Cython generates C code from it then compiles that into a `.dll`. You would need to treat the `.pyd` as a standard PE DLL and disassemble it, then recreate the python from what you understand of the assembly.